# Access deleted several records when data type changed. How to find which ones caused the errors?

Tags: database, microsoft-access, data-validation

I'm trying to work with an old Access database. It has a column formatted as Short Text that I need to change to numerical data.

To attempt to change the data type, I opened the Design View and changed the field's data type to Number. I then attempted to save my changes. Access showed the following error message:

> The size of one or more fields has been changed to a shorter size. If data is lost, validation rules may be violated as a result. Do you want to continue anyway?

I chose "Yes" and received this message:

> The contents of fields in 3 record(s) were deleted. Do you want to proceed anyway?

My question is, how do I figure out which three records are causing the errors? There are several thousand records in this table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a new column of type number, long integer, perhaps?
Then, use an UPDATE query to convert the short text to an integer, placing it in the new column.
You can sort the table by using the newly created number column.
Any fields that were not converted will be blank and will be listed at the top.
You can then fix them manually.
When all of the data is correct, delete the original column and rename the new column.